# How can I cast Generics in Java?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this code:

```
FVDTO.setStatus("fail");
List<String[]> invalidFields = new ArrayList<String[]>();
Iterator<ConstraintViolation<HazardSubmission>> iterator = cv.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    ConstraintViolation<HazardSubmission> i = iterator.next();
    String property = i.getPropertyPath().toString();
    String message = i.getMessage();
    invalidFields.add(new String[] { property, message });
}
FVDTO.setInvalidFields(invalidFields);
return new JsonResolution(FVDTO);
```

I've taken some out to keep things DRY so I can then use it with other classes, i.e HazardSubmission is one class, and there will be others. The below code shows my attempt, obviously manually casting `<HazardSubmission>` here won't work it needs to be like `o.getClass();`

```
public static List<String[]> GetInvalidProperties(Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> cv, Object o) {

  List<String[]> invalidFields = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  Iterator<ConstraintViolation<HazardSubmission>> iterator = cv.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    ConstraintViolation<HazardSubmission> i = iterator.next();
    String property = i.getPropertyPath().toString();
    String message = i.getMessage();
    invalidFields.add(new String[] { property, message });
 }
```

}

The second code block fails because I don't really know what I'm doing, I want to pass in the cv for param 1, with a general object type, then somehow pass in the type as a second paramter.

Could you someone please explain how to do this?

Comment: I haven't used hibernate, but the whole point of using generics so you don't have to cast

Comment: Why do you want `Object` in the parameter when your method is only working on `HazardSubmission`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for a generic method

```
public static <T> List<String[]> GetInvalidProperties(Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> cv){
   Iterator<ConstraintViolation<T>> iterator = cv.iterator();
   while(iterator.hasNext()) {
      ConstraintViolation<T> i = iterator.next();
      String property = i.getPropertyPath().toString();
      String message = i.getMessage();
      invalidFields.add(new String[] { property, message });
   }
}
```

If all T extends a given class or interface you could even say

```
public static <T extends MyClassOrInterface> List<String[]> GetInvalidProperties(Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> cv){
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cv.iterator()` will return you an `Iterator<ConstraintViolation<Object>>`, and you need `Iterator<ConstraintViolation<HazardSubmission>>`. This is done because cv is defined as `Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>>`. If you want a generic way for this, you can change

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> cv
```

to

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends Object>> cv
```

in that way your code will compile.